# Exibir mensagem de usuario bloqueado no membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

Preciso exibir uma mensagem quando o usuario bloqueado tentar logar no membership...
Defino o usuario bloqueado com a propriedade IsApproved = false; no momento do cadastro

```
MembershipUser lockUser = Membership.GetUser(txtEmail.Text);
lockUser.IsApproved = false;
Membership.UpdateUser(lockUser);
```

Existe alguma forma?

Comment: Como é que estás a definir um user bloqueado na bd?

Comment: Se puder explicar melhor o problema que tem em concreto e, se possível, mostrar código que já tenha feito onde se encontre esse problema. Está demasiado ampla a sua pergunta, veja na [Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Reformulei a pergunta, preciso agora exibir uma mensagem se o usuário não tiver desbloqueado o acesso que foi enviado por email.

Answer (score 3):

No seu botão de login:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser("Yourusername");

    if(user != null && !user.isApproved) {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
           this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('O usuário não está aprovado.');", true);
    }
}
```